# How to run function when json gives NetworkError: 503 Forbidden

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can I display a custom alert message when my json fails and gives me "NetworkError: 503 Service Unavailable? here is my code:

```
    $(function () {
        $.getJSON('https://freegeoip.net/json/?callback=?', function (location, textStatus, jqXHR) { 
            console.log(jqXHR);
        });
    });
```

Here is the error im getting:

```
    "NetworkError: 503 Service Unavailable - https://freegeoip.net/json/?callback=jQuery17107261589788513599_1457551270088&_=1457551270313"
```

I tried somthing like this but it didnt work:

```
    $.getJSON('https://freegeoip.net/json/?callback=?',error: alert('fail'), function (location, textStatus, jqXHR) {
```

Is there a default way of handling erros and creating custom function in this case? thanks!

Comment: You could use the standard `$.ajax` method along with it's `success` and `fail` properties. You could call `done()` and `fail()` from the Promise returned from `$.getJSON`, or you can use `$.ajaxSetup` to setup some default properties for all AJAX methods. Choice is yours :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change it to the `$.ajax` method, like so:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: 'https://freegeoip.net/json/?callback=?',
    success: function (data) {
        // Everything worked
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // Something went wrong
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

From jQuery web site:

Handling Errors

As of jQuery 1.5, you may use .fail() to account for errors:

```
$.getScript( "ajax/test.js" )
  .done(function( script, textStatus ) {
    console.log( textStatus );
  })
  .fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
    $( "div.log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxError handler." );
});
```